# Synchronize SKActions on two or more SKSpriteNode's?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I want to move two (or more) `SKSpriteNode`s in sync. Any difference will show. I tried to trigger the `SKAction` for each sprite in order and when the last one is finished it triggers a new move. But it turns out that the actions doesn't end in the same order they are started, which causes a slightly time difference that is noticeable.

Is there a way to run parallel `SKActions` on two or more sprites with a duration so that they end at exactly the same time or at least in the order they are started?

Here is an principle example of what is not working:

```
- (void)testMethod1{
SKSpriteNode *child_1=[arrayWithSprites objectAtIndex:1];
SKSpriteNode *child_2=[arrayWithSprites objectAtIndex:2];

//This doesn't work.
[child_1 runAction:[SKAction moveToX:20.0 duration:0.5]];
[child_2 runAction:[SKAction moveToX:20.0 duration:0.5] 
    completion:^{[self testMethod1];}];
//Actions might not be finished in the order they are started.
}
```

And here is a way I haven't tried yet but wonder if it might solve my problem:

```
- (void)testMethod2{
SKSpriteNode *child_1=[arrayWithSprites objectAtIndex:1];
SKSpriteNode *child_2=[arrayWithSprites objectAtIndex:2];

//Will this guarantee total syncronisation?
[self runAction:[SKAction group:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [SKAction runBlock:^{[child_1 runAction:[SKAction moveToX:20.0 duration:0.5]];}],
                                 [SKAction runBlock:^{[child_2 runAction:[SKAction moveToX:20.0 duration:0.5]];}],
                                 nil]]
      completion:^{[self testMethod2];}];
}
```

I hope my English and thoughts are understandable.

//Micke....

Comment: Did you try the group method ?

Answer (score 4):

Just add a container `SKNode`, and then they will both move at once:

```
SKNode *containerNode = [[SKNode alloc] init];    
[containerNode addChild:node1];    
[containerNode addChild:node2]; //add as many as necessary    
[containerNode runAction:someAction]; //declare the action you want them both to perform
```

Comment: This only works when the sprites moves in the exact same direction, but sometimes I need them to move in different direction, one to move in x-direction and the other in y-direction. Then a container don't work for me. The sprites are segments of snake moving inside a x/y-grid....

Comment: I found that with this solution, if the child nodes already have parent assigned, it failed with the following error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent

Answer (score 4):

The solution by Tyler works perfectly.

But if you can't or don't want to do that, you should know that very likely actions are multithreaded and thus they can finish in any order, but they should still finish in the same frame.

To ensure they both ran to completion before running testMethod, you should perform the code in didEvaluateActions. Then you need to find a way to figure out whether both actions have finished. One way is to use a key.

```
[child_1 runAction:[SKAction moveToX:20.0 duration:0.5] withKey:@"action1"];
[child_2 runAction:[SKAction moveToX:20.0 duration:0.5] withKey:@"action2"];
```

Then check if both of these actions have run to completion by checking if they still exist:

```
-(void) didEvaluateActions
{
    if ([child_1 actionForKey:@"action1"] == nil && 
        [child_2 actionForKey:@"action2"] == nil)
    {
        // both actions have ended, start new ones here ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use a completion block that both actions run. Increase a NSUInteger counter variable and in the block increase the counter by 1, then test if the counter's value is equal to (or greater) than the number of concurrent actions. If it is, you know that both actions have run to completion:

```
__block NSUInteger counter = 0;
void (^synchBlock)(void) = ^{
    counter++;
    if (counter == 2)
    {
        [self testMethod1];
    }
};

[child_1 runAction:[SKAction moveToX:20.0 duration:0.5] completion:synchBlock];
[child_2 runAction:[SKAction moveToX:20.0 duration:0.5] completion:synchBlock];
```

Comment: I have solved it with the exact way of your last alternative, a completion block on each action that sets a counter and then I wait until all counters are set to 1 before calling the movemethod again. But I thought there should be a better solution than that, maybe a group-action for multiple sprites that I missed existed and therefor I put out the question here....but maybe I have to be satisfied with the completion-block-solution...

Answer (score 0):

Is your framerate constant ? Your first example technically should work, however the completion order might be based on something else, like their draw order.

One concept you could employ is to temporarily encapsulate them in a container node, and then move just the container node via an action. When the action is complete remove them from the container and back to their original parent.

Are you finding that they move out of sync visually ? Or does your testMethod1 in some way require that both actions are complete ?

Although the container concept I have suggested will work for your specific example, it's not a valid option unless it's desired that the objects are moving as if they are connected. An example of where the container would not work, is if each object had to move to different locations in 1 second.

Comment: The completion order can differ, most likely because they are seperate threads, and if the last one ends before the first one it retriggers a new move before the first one has ended. Then they are no longer in sync visually, and if this repeats the unsync gets more and more visual. I hoped there would be a function that ensure that the actions are performed parallel or at least in order....

Comment: I am not sure what specifies the order, it's worth investigating as it would be the ideal solution in that you could set your completion method for both and see if it's consistent. If it's consistent, then we might be able to gleen why. If it's not consistent, then another approach is likely best.